# undefined value from data attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i try to get the value from the data attribute and pass to the java script variable but it give the undefined value

```js
    $(document).on("click","#edit_cust",function(){
        var customer_id=$(this).data("id");
        var customer_name=$(this).data("name");
        var customer_phone=$(this).data("phone");
        var customer_addr=$(this).data("mail");
        var customer_mail=$(this).data("phone");   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='btn-group' role='group' >
     <a id="edit_cust" data-target="#edit" data-toggle="modal"><button 
     type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' data-id="<?php echo 
     $customer["cus_id"]; ?>" data-name="<?php echo $customer["cus_name"]; ?>" 
     data-phone="<?php echo $customer["cus_phone"]; ?>" data-addr="<?php echo 
     $customer["cus_address"]; ?>" data-mail="<?php echo $customer["cus_mail"]; ? 
     >"><span class="fas fa-user-edit edit_data" aria-hidden='true'></span> 
     </button></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `#edit_cust` only has `data-target` and `data-toggle`. Maybe you need to use the `button` as selector?

Comment: Please format your HTML for readability.

Comment: Please also remove PHP tag as it has nothing to do with PHP other than possible XSS.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Why did you add the snippet?

Comment: @Dharman Why not? It makes copying the code into an answer very simple and doesn't change your ability to read and understand the question. The fact that you can't actually run this particular bit of code is besides the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those data attributes are present for the inner `button` so get the `button` within the clicked element.

```
$(document).on("click","#edit_cust",function(){
    // cache buttton reference
    var $btn = $('button', this);
    // or $btn = $(this).find('button');

    // get values from button
    var customer_id = $(btn.data("id");
    var customer_name = $btn.data("name");
    var customer_phone = $btn.data("phone");
    var customer_addr = $btn.data("mail");
    var customer_mail = $btn.data("phone");   
});
```